# Lewis Carroll's logic problem: Proving that opium eaters do not wear white kid gloves.

Tags: logic

> If he goes to a party, he does not fail to brush his hair. To look fascinating it is necessary to be tidy. If he is an opium eater, then he has no self-command. If he brushes his hair, he looks fascinating. He wears white kid gloves only if he goes to a party. Having no self-command is sufficient to make one look untidy. Therefore, opium eaters do not wear white kid gloves.
>
> **P** : He goes to a party.
> **B**: He does not brush his hair.
> **F**: He looks fascinating.
> **T**: He looks tidy.
> **O**: He is an opium eater.
> **S**: He has self-command.
> **G**: He wears white kid gloves.

I have been trying to solve this logic problem for days, but every time I get stuck. I have also tried to solve it with 'Proof by contradiction' but it was worthless.

Comment: Start writing down the clauses: "If he goes to a party, he does not fail to brush his hair" will be $P \to \lnot B$

Comment: I have done it and used logical equivalences  but i still couldn't solve it

Comment: @Max Please show us what you have done, and where you got stuck.

Comment: But the [version I've found](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~hile/math100/logice.htm) is with predicate logic...

Comment: Whenever you have any doubt of what implication is true given a predicate, ask these two questions (for example with the F and T predicate): "Is it possible for any person to look fascinating but not be tidy?", "Is it possible to be tidy and not look fascinating?". In this case, the answers are "No" and "Yes" respectively, which indicates the implication is $F\rightarrow T$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With (please, note change in B):

P : He goes to a party.

B: He brushes his hair.

F: He looks fascinating.

T: He looks tidy.

O: He is an opium eater.

S: He has self-command.

G: He wears white kid gloves.

IMO we must have:

1. $P \to B$
2. $F \to T$
3. $O \to \lnot S$
4. $B \to F$
5. $G \to P$
6. $\lnot S \to \lnot T$

> *Conclusion*: $O \to \lnot G$.

The solution is straightforward, with some contrapositions.

---

*Added*

"B is a *necessary* condition for A" is $A \to B$.

Why so? Because it means that we cannot have $A$ without $B$, and thus the case $A$ True and $B$ False is not possible.

Thus, "(in order) To look Fascinating, it is necessary to be Tidy" reads (thanks to ACheca): "To be Tidy is a necessary condition to look Fascinating", that sounds quite natural.

Comment: I think the second one should be $F\rightarrow T$. If you look fascinating, necessarily you're tidy. The opposite isn't true (and it makes the conclusion impossible to prove).

Comment: Thanks ! My mistake was that i used T→F and by solving this mistake , i could solve this problem !

Comment: @Max - you are welcome :-)

Comment: even though I solved this question, I still have this question, why it is  F-> T, even though it was 'To look fascinating it is necessary to be tidy.' , I thought, because of 'necessary', that it should be T-> F. Could you explain to me why it was accepted that way?